# Can I have a heroku free application with domain?

Tags: heroku, dns

I would like to put a domain in my free heroku app, because I don't have a international credit card (I would like to pay, if it is possible with debit card, if it is how can I pay with a debit card?). The domain is a Brazilian domain, and I would like to know if is possible with a free account, and how can I do this? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can have custom domain names for free apps as well, checkout: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

> Domains can be added to both free and paid Heroku apps and adding
>   domains does not incur extra charges. For verification purposes, you
>   must verify your Heroku account to add domains to apps.

As for payments, as long as it's a Visa/Master Card (or such) debit card, you can simply put those details in the billing section and it'll work fine. I've been using such a card to pay for heroku services for quite some time now.

Comment: It means we can't add custom domains without filling payment information, right?

Comment: @SalahAdDin Yes